# OpenCV VideoCapture not opens file ios

Tags: ios, opencv, video-capture

I've saved a video to a file using:

```
NSString *documentsDirectory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
documentsDirectory = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"test9.avi"];

NSLog(@"Open to: %@", documentsDirectory);

std::string fileName([documentsDirectory cString], [documentsDirectory cStringLength]);
videoWriter = new cv::VideoWriter(fileName, CV_FOURCC('H', 'F', 'Y', 'U'), 25, cvSize(288,352),1);
```

But I can't open this with VideoCapture:

```
NSLog(@"Load the video");
videoCapture = new cv::VideoCapture();
NSLog(@"Video loaded");
if (videoCapture->open(fileName))
{
    NSLog(@"Opened");
}
else {
    NSLog(@"Failed to open");
}
```

There is no error from the VideoCapture itself just my log "Failed to open" ...
Can I somehow get more detailed error log?

Comment: Do you want to process a single frame out of your video or the whole file?

Comment: I want to process the whole file. I'm the one who records the file so I could record it to any format. Right now I'm implementing a simple dump cv::Mat to a binary file approach and read it back the same way... This way I don't have to use VideoCapture.

Answer (score 2):

```
cv::VideoCapture capture;
NSString* pathToInputFile = [NSString documentPathByAppendingPath:@"Video/sample_iTunes.mov"];
if(capture.open(std::string([pathToFile UTF8String]))){
    NSLog(@"Opened");
}else{
    NSLog(@"Failed to open");
}
```

works fine for me

Answer (score 0):

While Kirill's answer would have worked when it was posted, that is no longer the case now.

The following works in Xcode 8.2.1, replacing the `documentPathByAppendingPath` function that is no longer available.

```
cv::VideoCapture cap;
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"MyVideo" ofType:@"MOV"];
if ( cap.open ( std::string( path.UTF8String ) ) ) {
    NSLog(@"Opened");
} else {
    NSLog(@"Failed to open");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I met this problem using Swift 3.
Thanks to answers by [Kirill](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12433280/opencv-videocapture-not-opens-file-ios#14832846) and [CodeBender](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12433280/opencv-videocapture-not-opens-file-ios#42618847), I solved this.

```
let resourceURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "test", withExtension: "MOV")
let openCVVideoCapture = OpenCVVideoCaptureWrapper.init(file: resourceURL?.path)
```

and following is my `OpenCVVideoCaptureWrapper.mm`

```
@implementation OpenCVVideoCaptureWrapper {

    cv::VideoCapture video;
}

- (instancetype)initWithFile:(NSString*) filePath  {

    std::string cvFilePath = [filePath UTF8String];
    video = cv::VideoCapture(cvFilePath);

    if (!video.isOpened()) NSLog(@"Could not open file");

    return self;
}
@end
```

Answer (score 0):

This snippet worked for me in Xcode 10, Swift 4. Thanks to @Nathan Tuggy.

```
- (void)openVideoFile:(NSURL *)fileName {

    NSString *filename = fileName.path;
    std::string filePath = [filename UTF8String];

    cv::VideoCapture capture(filePath);

    if (!capture.isOpened()) {
        printf("@Error Opening video file");
        // failed, print error message
    }
    else {
        printf("File Opened");
    }
}
```